# Rails Display Helper Method containing Instance Variable on Separate Controller's Show

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not really able to affect a flash message's location as it's being brought in through the CMS and my affects to do like an ignore flash on a current page have failed.

So my thought it do try to pass along an instance variable onto a different controller's show page. I read that the best way to handle that is by passing it onto a helper.

My model structure is like this:

```
Event
has_many :occupants

Occupant
belongs_to :event
```

Occupant is being handled on the show page of Events using a form_tag that looks like:

```
=form_tag import_admin_occupants_path, multipart: true, class:'import' do
 =hidden_field_tag 'event_id', @event.id
 =file_field_tag :file, accept: 'text/csv', class: 'form-inline', required: true
 =link_to 'Download template', root_path + 'import.csv', target: '_blank'
 =submit_tag 'Import', class: 'btn btn-primary', id: 'csv-import', disabled: true
```

I'm allowing for importing of a CSV of data and throwing out the errors along with what row and error message. The issue is that it's all run together like:

```
Row 1: Name can't be blank. City can't be blank. Row 3: Address can't be blank. Row 7: City can't be blank.
```

And I would like to break it into it's own row/list items.

The Occupant Controller looks like:

```
def import
 @occupant = Occupant::Import.run(params[:file].path, params[:event_id]).result
 if @occupant.empty?
  flash[:notice] = 'Succes'
 else
  flash_helper(@occupant)
 end
 redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
end
```

I made sure to include at the top of the controller

```
include EventsHelper
```

Then in the EventsHelper:

```
def flash_helper(occupant)
 occupant.to_a
end
```

Then I run into the issue on Event > Show

```
h1 Import Occupants
-flash_helper.each do |k,v|
 =k
```

This fails out with

> wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)

Is there a way to display this helper only from the import side as that appears to be the issue?

I've tried a vast array of different ways to handle this like:

- flash[:error] = @occupant.to_a.join('
  ').html_safe. This shows the br within the text
- flash[:error] = @occupant.to_a.join('\n'). Although technically it "shows" a new line it's actually only showing within the text element on the HTML so it still appears as lumped together in the flash box.
- @occupant.each_with_index { |k,v| flash[:error] = k }. This will only show the very last error.

And since I want it to stay on the same page it's not as though I can render a partial on the else statement.

Ultimately what I'm wanting to view is only the occupant errors on the Event > Show page using a helper as I believe it's the last option available.

Comment: What do you mean when you say separate controller's show page? If you need to pass info between controllers and actions you'd typically store them in the "params" hash.

Comment: The OccupantController is handling the import but is being displayed on the Event > Show page. So if I'm looking at say "Meet and Greet Event" which is being handled by the EventController it has a form for Occupants.

Answer (score 0):

That helper method only receives the occupant value and call's `to_a` on it, it doesn't store anything for you to use later.

If you want the errors to show on different lines, use HTML's BR tag to show a line break:

```
flash[:error] = @occupant.to_a.join('<br />').html_safe
```

I'm not sure I understand the flow of requests/pages from your description though.

Comment: Yeah I've tried join('<br />').html_safe and join('\n'). Neither of those are working. It might be a constraint on the flash section from the CMS that's affecting it. Which is why I'm trying to display the Occupant issues through a different method than the flash.